# Why jQuery UI formatDate showing unexpected output?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet to convert the string date into specified date format. For example, here I want to show date in year-month-day format. I was expecting for 2017-11-28 but the result was 1970-01-01. How can I get the expected result.

```js
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd",new Date(11/28/2017));

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `new Date(11/28/2017)` == `new Date(0.0001947730009207451)`.  You want `new Date("11/28/2017")`.

Comment: Make sure to create the right Date-Object. `new Date(11/28/2017)` returns `Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass `string` to `new Date()`

```
new Date('11/28/2017')
```

Now you pass the mathematical expression - `11/28/2017 = 0.0001947730009207451`

Comment: this will return "1970-01-01".

Comment: @KiranShahi have you even tried that? No, because the code above returns '2017-11-28'

Answer (score 2):

```
$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd",new Date('11/28/2017'));
```

try using it directly in the console and than executing it in your file-code

this code returns "2017-11-28" in my console

Answer (score -1):

Format your date like below:

```
$("#txtStartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy MM dd',
  altField: '#dateFormat'
});
```